# Grails refresh div

Tags: ajax, grails, html

I have something like this in my website:

```
<body>
<div id="1">
content1
</div>
<div id="2">
content2
</div>

<g:render template="/layouts/aa1"/>

<g:form name="myForm" action="myaction">
<g:submitButton name="update" value="Update" />
</g:form>
</body>
```

My aa1 layout is something like this:

```
<div id="3">
       <g:each in="print">
       ${it.carModel}
       </g:each>

</div>
```

And the controller is:

```
def updateDiv = {
def max = 20
def offset = 0 
   if(params=["myForm"]){
       def print = Cars.list(max: max, offset: offset + 10)
   }
render(template:'aa1', [print: print])
}
```

What i wanna do is, when i click 'Update', g:render is called again and updated with ajax (update only that part), and the values change. Each time is clicked, the next 20 cars are shown. How can i accomplish that? Am i in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails has a tag [`formRemote`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) that does this for you.
Basically, instead of using the regular `form` tag, you use a `formRemote` tag, specifying the controller and action to invoke and the dom element to update with the results.
You can also look at the [`submitToRemote`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html) tag which does something similar.

I've stubbed out some code below s oset you on the right direction. Its not tested so there might be errors in it

CONTROLLER:

```
def updateDiv = {
    def max = 20
    def offset = 0 

    if(params=["myForm"]){
       def print = Cars.list(max: max, offset: offset + 10)
    }

    render(template:'aa1', collection:print, var:'car')
}
```

GSP:

```
<body>
    <div id="1">
        content1
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        content2
    </div>

    <g:formRemote name="myForm" on404="alert('not found!')" update="3"
              url="[ controller: 'YourControllerName', action:'updateDiv' ]">
        Book Id: <input name="id" type="text"></input>
    </g:formRemote>

    <div id="3">
         <g:render id="" template="/layouts/aa1" collection="${print}"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

TEMPLATE:

```
${car.carModel}
```